# How to loop sequentially through images in one folder and compare with the latest image in another folder

Tags: imagemagick, zsh

I am trying to use the shell to loop sequentially through images in one folder and compare with the latest image in another folder.

One error i'm getting is -

```
zsh: no matches found: /TiffOut/*.tiff(.om[1])
```

Though I wouldn't be surprised if that's not the only problem.

What I'm hoping to acheive is:

- Loop through all source images in current directory:
- Put most recent file from TiffOut subdirectory in variable 'latest'
- Compare current source, and latest output with '-evaluate-sequence max' to  create new tiff with the brightest parts from each image_file
- Save to TiffOut subdirectory

Here's my full script -

```
#! /bin/zsh -
filelist=$(ls | grep '.tiff')
for image_file in $filelist
do
latest=$(/TiffOut/*.tiff(.om[1]))
magick $image_file $latest -evaluate-sequence Max '/TiffOut/out_${imagefile}.tiff'
done
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your script - give this one a try:

```
#!/bin/zsh

for image_file in *.tiff
do
  latest=(./TiffOut/*.tiff(.om[1]))
  magick "$image_file" "$latest" -evaluate-sequence Max "./TiffOut/out_${image_file}"
done
```

Some notes:

- You don't need `grep` to narrow down the file list; just use a glob pattern (`*.tiff`).
- Subdirectories are relative to the current directory, which is `.`, hence `./TiffOut/*.tiff`.  Paths beginning with `/` are absolute, starting at the root directory.
- The assignment that gets the latest file is using another glob pattern, with the `.om` glob qualifiers.  It's not a command, which is what `$(...)` indicates. With just the parentheses, it's an assignment of an array, with a single member.
- Variables (e.g. `$something`) are only expanded in strings quoted with double-quotes, not single quotes.
- I don't know enough about imagemagick to tell you if the `magick` command does what you want.

You may be able to use the terms in my notes to find more information about the pieces of the script.
Good luck!